# UIWebView subclass causing malloc_zone_unregister() in XCode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I'm running my project in XCode 7 and I'm trying to hunt down some **EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS** which my users on the AppStore are experiencing.  
I'm running XCode 7 with Enable Address Sanitizer on. After the app starts and all the init is done I see these warnings int the console:

```
IKMS(1001,0x60081000) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x1a8ad000
==1001==__asan_mz_destroy() called -- ignoring
IKMS(1001,0x60081000) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x1a8b0000
==1001==__asan_mz_destroy() called -- ignoring
IKMS(1001,0x60081000) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x1a8ab000
==1001==__asan_mz_destroy() called -- ignoring
```

After some debugging I found that this happens when during my initial allocation in the AppDelegate of the app, if I create a CustomWebview and set it's frame when the app becomes active this error appears.

This is the init function of the custom UIWebView:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is how I initialise it:

```
CustomUIWebView *custom = [[CustomUIWebView alloc] init];
custom.frame = CGRectMake(109/2, 220/2, 326/2, 326/2);
[anotherView addSubview:custom];
```

If I move this line:

```
custom.frame = CGRectMake(109/2, 220/2, 326/2, 326/2);
```

After the app becomes active the errors go away.
This of course is part of a bigger project and I **fixed all error**s like this but I still get these errors in the console. So basically I have these questions:

- Are there any other views that behave like this?
- Do you know by any chance why this error occurs? EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS Maybe besides memory overwrite and out of
  memory?
- Is there way to catch these errors when they happen rather than when
  they crash the app? (The memory ones).

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Do you know by any chance why this error occurs? EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS Maybe besides memory overwrite and out of memory?

You should execute the designated initializer, when you step up from a subclass' initializer. The designated initializer for `UIView` and its subclass `UIWebView` is [`-initWithFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:), not `-init`. To do so, you have to pass a frame rest to your initializer or to set a default one. So it should be (option 1):

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
  {
  …
  }
  return self;
}
…
CustomUIWebView *custom = [[CustomUIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(109/2, 220/2, 326/2, 326/2)];
```

BTW: Do you know, that `109/2` is an integer division with the result 54, *not* 54.5?

> 1. Are there any other views that behave like this?

I do not know, whether views behaves exactly like this. But almost every view will need to know the frame at initialization.

> 3. Is there way to catch these errors when they happen rather than when they crash the app? (The memory ones).

I'm not sure, what you want to say. Maybe exception breakpoint?

Comment: Hey, I've tried this but it still doesn't work, still getting the same error. If I set up the frame after the full init of the app, it works.

Comment: maybe the view hierarchy is not completely set-up so inserting a view fails because of non-initialized data.